# Allowing custom scp/sftp/rsync in sandbox shell

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh, docker

I am currently building a sandbox environment utilizing docker where all users will be directly guided into a docker container with home dir linked as data vol upon login. This is achieved through the use of a custom user shell instead of /bin/bash csh etc.

However, scp/rsync/sftp fails with this custom shell unfortunately. My current solution is to make a separate no-login account with the same home dir as the sandbox user and only allow scp/rsync/sftp through rssh in this account where users can then upload their data.

Just wondering if I can streamline this process somehow and use only 1 account to redirect users into docker containers directly AND allow sftp/scp processes as well?

Thanks!

Edit:

upon more poking around, I have discovered that the newest sshd internal-ftp-server subsystem do not invoke the users login shell, and I can enable sftp this way. However, i dont think rsync and scp works this way unfortunately.

The ultimate goal i want is basically to be able to sandbox users directly into a container upon login and to allow sftp/scp/rsync upload ideally using the SAME credentials instead of setting up a separate one for them.

Comment: Are SCP/SFTP/Rsync sessions supposed to run inside the docker container, or outside of it? If you want to extend your custom shell to cover those kinds of sessions, you should describe how this shell works and include the relevant source code.

Comment: You may also find this useful: http://superuser.com/a/928844/54530

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, and I'm having the same problem with SFTP.  

My wrapper script the executes `docker` also sets up temporary `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files, and mounts those into the container with `-v`.  I found I had to use `--user UID:GID` and `--group-add GUID` in addition to this.  I'm attempting to check the `-c` argument to the wrapper script, and if set, I use that for the `--entrypoint` argument.